# How to convert NSData into NSAttributedString with out using initWithRTFD of NSAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdata

We are invoking `initWithRTFD` of `NSAttributesString` to convert `NSData` to `attributedString`. From the `NSTextView` we are reading string converting that into `NSData`, Converted `NSData` passing to `initWithRTFD` API.

Problem here is, if we pass huge length of Data to convert as `AttributedString` it takes bit time to convert. We would like to know, if there are any other options to convert `NSData` into `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: If u can show us, what u have tried than it will be easy to answer for your question

Comment: Hi lmmi, This what I'm doing :  NSRange modifiableRegion = [NSTextView modifiableRegion];
    
    NSData* rtfData = [NSTextView RTFDFromRange:modifiableRegion];
    
    NSAttributedString* attrString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTFD:rtfData documentAttributes:nil] autorelease];

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `NSTextView`'s `- (NSTextStorage *)textStorage`. `NSTextStorage` is a subclass of `NSMutableAttributedString` (which conforms to `@protocol NSCoding`). Then you can create data from an attributed string and back.

If your 'data' is an RTFD, you're already doing what you should do.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. This method also takes a bit  long time when   string is huge

Comment: @Ajay If it's 'huge', maybe you should profile and consider how it can be broken up. If you're still stumped, you could always throw the question out here on SO. I can't really recommend, given what I know now.